# Lagrange multiplier - space probe

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

i am stuck on this question which uses the Lagrange multiplier. I am trying to construct the equations using the partial derivatives but the $x$'s and $y$'s cancel. can anyone help?

A space probe in the shape of the ellipsoid

$x^2 + y^2 + 3z^2 = 3$

enters a planet's atmosphere and begins to heat up. The temperature on its surface is found
to be
$T(x, y, z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 6z$:

Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the hottest points on the probe's surface.

Comment: What do  you know regarding Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: I know the method. so I have set the first equation as $g$ and the second as $f$. Then I took the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$ and then set $f=\lambda*g$

Comment: Right.  Now set the individual vector elements equal to each other.  Along with the equation $x^2+y^2+3x^2=3$, you have 4 equations with 4 unknowns.  You have $f_x=\lambda g_x, f_y=\lambda g_y, f_z=\lambda g_z,$

Comment: Yes, i did that but the problem I am having is that for the first two equations the x and y's are cancelling so i can't find x and y in terms of $\lambda$

Comment: like for example i have $2x=\lambda*2x$ so i can't write $x$ in terms of $\lambda$

Comment: But you now have that $\lambda=1$.  Then $4y=\lambda\cdot 2y$ implies that $4y=2y$ and thus $y=0$, And $6=\lambda\cdot 6z$ which implies that $6=6z$ and thus $z=1$.  Now you can solve for x...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the gradient of $T$,
$$\nabla T=(T_x,T_y,T_z)=(2x,4y,6)$$
Taking the gradient of $g$ times $\lambda$,
$$\lambda\nabla g=(\lambda g_x,\lambda g_y,\lambda g_z)=(\lambda 2x,\lambda 2,\lambda g_x)$$
Setting them equal
$$2x=\lambda 2x \Rightarrow 2x(1-\lambda)=0$$
$$4y=\lambda 2y \Rightarrow 2y(2-\lambda)=0$$
$$6=\lambda 6z \Rightarrow \lambda=\frac1{z}$$
So what if $\lambda=1$?  Then from the second equation, $2y=0$ and thus $y=0$.  Also, fron the third equation, we have $1=\frac1{z}$ and thus, $z=1$.  Plugging into the constraint equation, we have 
$$x^2+0^2+3(1)^2=3$$
$$x^2+3=3$$
$$x^2=0$$
$$x=0$$
Thus the critical point when $\lambda =1$ is $(0,0,1)$.

What if $\lambda=2$?  Then from the first equation, $2x(-1)=-2x=0$ and thus $x=0$.  Also, from the third equation, we have $2=\frac1{z}$ and thus $z=\frac1{2}$.  Plugging into the constraint equation we have
$$0^2+y^2+3\left(\frac1{2}\right)^2=3$$
$$y^2+\frac3{4}=3$$
$$y^2=\frac9{4}$$
$$y=\pm\frac3{2}$$
Thus the critical points when $\lambda =2$ is $(0,\pm\frac3{2},\frac1{2})$.

In the case that $x=0$ and $y=0$, we can simply plug $x$ and $y$ into the constraint equation and solve for $z$
$$0^2+0^2+3z^2=3$$
$$3z^2=3$$
$$z^2=1$$
$$z=\pm1$$
Thus the critical points when $x=0,y=0$ is $(0,0,\pm1)$.

Finally, plugging the critical points into $T$
$$T(0,0,1)=0^2+2\cdot0^2+6\cdot 1=6$$
$$T(0,0,-1)=0^2+2\cdot0^2+6\cdot(-1)=-6$$
$$T\left(0,\pm\frac3{2},\frac1{2}\right)=0^2+2\cdot\left(\pm\frac3{2}\right)^2+6\left(\frac1{2}\right)=\frac9{2}+3=\frac{15}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! for some reason I hadn't considered the fact that x,y or z could be zero! Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: This is wrong. It's easy to see that $T\left(0, \dfrac 3 2, \dfrac 1 2\right)=\dfrac{15}2\ge 1=T(0,0,1)$. Why you are equating the gradients to one another ie beyond me. Further more $2x=\lambda 2x \Rightarrow \lambda=1$ isn't true.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done Lagrange Multipliers, but i was definitely taught to set the individual vector components equal to each other in order to get 3 equations in x,y,z and $\lambda$ as well as include the constraint equation to get 4 equations in 4 unknowns.  Why wouldn't I want to set them equal?

Comment: Okay, I just checked the wikipedia page, so I see how you got the $\Lambda$ mapping. I also see that $x\neq 0$ if $\lambda=1$. Sorry for the confusion, especially to the OP... I also can't delete my answer....

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Fix it then. If you've looked at my answer, it might be inevitable that you'll be essentially copying what I did. That's fine by me.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\Lambda \colon\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R, (x,y,z,\lambda)\mapsto x^2+2y^2+6z+\lambda (x^2+y^2+3z^2-3)$.

Let $(x,y,z,\lambda)\in \mathbb R^4$.

The following holds:

$$\begin{cases} \Lambda _x(x,y,z,\lambda)&=2x+2\lambda x\\ \Lambda _y(x,y,z,\lambda)&=4y+2\lambda y\\ \Lambda_z(x,y,z, \lambda)&=6+6\lambda _z\\ \Lambda _\lambda(x,y,z,\lambda)&=x^2+y^2+3z^2-3.\end{cases}$$

Suppose $$\begin{cases} 0&=2x+2\lambda x\\ 0&=4y+2\lambda y\\ 0&=6+6\lambda z\\ 0&=x^2+y^2+3z^2-3,\end{cases}$$

then $$\begin{cases} 0&=(1+\lambda)x\\ 0&=(2+\lambda)y\\ \lambda&=-\dfrac1 z \land z\neq 0\neq \lambda \\ 0&=x^2+y^2+3z^2-3,\end{cases}$$

which implies $$\begin{cases} \lambda =-1\lor x=0\\ \lambda =-2 \lor y=0\\ \lambda=-\dfrac1 z \land z\neq 0\neq \lambda \\ x^2+y^2+3z^2-3=0.\end{cases}$$

$\boxed{\text{Case }\lambda =-1}$

It follows that $y=0$ and $z=1$. Thus $x^2+0+3-3=0$ and $x=0$, yielding the critical point $\color{blue}{(0,0,1)}$.

$\boxed{\text{Case }x=0}$

- $\boxed{\text{Sub case }\lambda =-2}$ It comes $z=\dfrac 1 2$ and $x^2+y^2-\dfrac 9 4=0$, that is $y=\pm\dfrac 3 2$, yielding the critical points $\color{blue}{\left(0, \dfrac 3 2, \dfrac 1 2\right)}$ and $\color{blue}{\left(0, -\dfrac 3 2, \dfrac 1 2\right)}$.
- $\boxed{\text{Sub case }y=0}$ It comes $0+0+3z~2-3=0$, that is, $z=\pm 1$, yielding the critical points $\color{blue}{(0,0,-1)}$ and $\color{blue}{(0,0,1)}$.

Now just check where it is hotter.